# How to count number of words in every line in opened text file?

Tags: php

OPen document in php for reading `$file = fopen(‘’file.txt‘’, ´r´);` - and how i can count words in every line of the document? Not count all words in document or count number of lines. I need number of words in every single line. Thank you

Comment: foreach each line split count store in array.

Comment: There is no need to SHOUT AT US.

Comment: I Am really sorry about that. Can you please show me how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to open file is to use built in function `file()`. It will read the file into an array (per line). Then use a cycle `foreach` to count the words in every line:

```
 $lines = file("myfile.txt");
 foreach($lines as $line) $words[] = str_word_count($line);
```

Now array `$words` contains number of words in every line `$lines` with a common index.

Comment: Can you please explain me the code from beginining to the end ? For better understanding of this problem

Comment: How can i array $words in every line $lines after that ?

Comment: In the first row you read your file to array (per line). In the next and final row you adding an element to the array `$words` with the number of words, getting by function `str_word_count`

Comment: can you please post me the full code of this problem ?

Comment: This is the full code. It seems you need to learn PHP more deeper. Explained code above is very simple to understand.

Comment: So, first i want to thank you very much ;)  so: <?php  $lines = file("myfile.txt");
 foreach($lines as $line) $words[] = str_word_count($line); ?> It is full code? No echo ? Maybe its primitive, but i want to uderstand it. Thank you

Comment: As I said above, array `$words` contains number of words in every line `$lines` with a common `index`. You know better how to use variables further.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$wordsCount = array_map(function ($v) {
    return str_word_count($v);
}, file("file.txt"));

print_r($wordsCount);
```

Comment: Is this really for each line ?

Comment: I think he's asking the number of words PER line.

Comment: @Virus721 see your point .. code updated .. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain me the code from beginining to the end ?